# Как получить email из страницы с JavaScript

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Осваиваю скрепинг, парсинг. Использую: Python и библиотеку BeautifulSoup. Надо заскрепить данные с множества страниц ([пример страницы](http://findyourvacationhome.com/find.php?property=5068927)).

В частности, надо вытащить email. Вот место в html-коде, где находится email.

```
<tr><td>Email:</td><td width="10"></td><td><script>var ylhrfq = "&#121;&#112;&#114;";var bdnd = "&#97;&#105;&#108;";var byil = "&#115;&#116;&#46;&#99;";var bwdbdf = "&#97;&#103;&#101;&#64;";var dqiex = "&#46;&#99;";var pner = "&#111;&#109;";var qkfow = "&#103;&#109;";var azzl = "&#105;&#101;";var hgcr = "&#110;&#46;&#112;&#108;";var link = byil + ylhrfq + azzl + hgcr + bwdbdf + qkfow + bdnd + dqiex + pner;var text = link;document.write('<a href="mailto:'+link+'"  />'+text+'</a>');</script></td></tr>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это с BeautifulSoup? Если да, то как этого можно добиться?

Comment: Базу данных для спама собираете, небось?

Comment: Возможно, собираю не для себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если получен доступ к такому блоку кода, то легко можно извлечь содержимое блока `script`, но дальше BeautifulSoup не поможет: парсить JavaScript он не умеет.

Можно заметить, что структура итогового кода проста: есть переменная `link`, которая является суммой нескольких других текстовых переменных, в которых стандартным html кодированием записаны части email.

Так как код довольно простой, можно его распарсить регулярными выражениями.

Например, выражение

```
re.findall('var (\w+) = "(.+?)"', script_code)
```

найдёт все переменные вида `var name = "string"`, а это все переменные-части итогового email.

Узнать порядок их следования можно через разбор присваивания значения переменной `link`:

```
re.search('var link = (.+?);', script_code).group(1).split(' + ')
```

Здесь мы находим присваивание переменной `link`, берём присвоенное значение и разбиваем по символу плюс.

После этого остаётся только собрать содержимое переменных в нужном порядке и декодировать текст, с этим поможет стандартная библиотека [`html`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html), если более конкретно, то функция [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape).

В итоге у меня получился следующий код:

```
def extract_email(code):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(code, 'lxml')
    script_code = soup.script.string

    variables = {name: html.unescape(value) 
                 for name, value in re.findall('var (\w+) = "(.+?)"', script_code)}
    order = re.search('var link = (.+?);', script_code).group(1).split(' + ')
    return ''.join(variables[name] for name in order)
```

Comment: Тимофей, спасибо большое за такое подробное объяснение. Всё работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Можете для начала xpath'ем получить данные внутри определенного тега td, а потом просто RegExp'ом собираете весь текст в кавычках, объединяете его и декодируете. В общем-то ничего сложного.